# Answering a question with a one-sided test - which direction is implied?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

An employer asks to perform a one-sided hypothesis to answer the following question:

> Are housing prices in your regional market higher than the national market average of 288407?

What's the implied null and alternative hypotheses in this question? Do we test the null hypothesis that the housing price average is less than or equal to 288407,

$$H_0: \mu \le 288407$$
$$H_A: \mu > 288407$$

or is it the other way around, and we test the null hypothesis that the house price average is larger than or equal to 288407,

$$H_0: \mu \ge 288407$$
$$H_A: \mu < 288407$$

Or is it implied that we should look at the dataset, notice the direction of the effect, and define our $H_0$ and $H_A$ to get significant results - leading us to biased inference?

Comment: Assuming you’re only interested in one-side, I would go with the former. As for your other concern, no. You should specify $H_0$ and $H_A$ before the test.

Answer (score 1):

No, you never look at the data before stating your hypothesis. This is called data snooping.

Null hypotheses are written as equalities,$^{\dagger}$ as we need one value of the parameter to give the test statistic distribution under the null hypothesis. With that in mind, you want to show $\mu>288407$, so that would be your alternative with $\mu=288407$ as the null.

$^{\dagger}$As the comment suggests, if you study more statistical theory, you’ll learn why this isn’t quite true. You’ll also learn why it is appropriate to phrase it this way in an introductory-level discussion. The gist is that we have to have a distribution under the null hypothesis from which we calculate the p-value or critical value.

Comment: Null hypotheses are not always written as equalities - consider composite null hypotheses.